# Show an element from a specific second in video Vimeo

Tags: video, vimeo

I wish I could show a div when a video on Vimeo reach two minutes, for example.

Comment: how you achieved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. Here's the Vimeo documentation on controlling their player through Javascript

https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

And here's an example they posted that uses the Froogaloop library/api

http://player.vimeo.com/playground